# Configuring Analytics for a magento store

Tags: magento, google-analytics

I have been maintaining a magento store technical aspect for few months and still learning. The google analytics shows the number of visitors and sources but there is no info regarding the content. When I went into the admin section, I was surprised to see that google analytics was enabled but still we could see the visitors count and other basic info.

While going through the code, I saw that analytics script was hard-coded in the footer of the website. All, I want to know is that, Is this a correct way to configure analytics for a magento site. And if yes, then why i cannot see any content details regarding the pages of website.

Or should I just remove the hard-coded code from the footer and enable the analytics through admin > sales > google api.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, since there is already a section in the Magento Configuration you just need to insert the Account number. It may take a few minutes to verify and track your store.

Just found this tutorial, please check the link below:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-google-analytics

Answer (score 1):

The integrated analytics in Magento works well (and probably makes more sense than to include tracking code in the template). However since Magento uses a one-page checkout process you can't per default do an funnel visualization on the checkout process.

I had to manually amend the tracking function in \skin\frontend\base\default\js\optcheckout.js (somewhere around line 110 in the file for a Magento 1.7 installation).

Find the function gotoSection and include a virtual pageview:

```
gotoSection: function(section)
{
    try {
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/checkout/onepage/' + section + '/']);
    } catch(err) {
        // do nothing
    }
    var sectionElement = $('opc-'+section);
    section = $('opc-'+section);
    sectionElement.addClassName('allow');
    this.accordion.openSection('opc-'+section);
    this.reloadProgressBlock(section);
},
```

That way every step of the checkout (billing adress, shipping address etc) will show up as a single pageview in the Analytics backend and you can set up goals and funnels for the checkout to see where visitors exit the checkout process.

Answer (score 0):

An additional information based on Eike's answer: if you're using Universal Analytics you should use this script in the gotoSection:

```
gotoSection: function (section, reloadProgressBlock) {

    try {
        ga('send', 'pageview', '/checkout/onepage/' + section + '/');
    } catch(err) {
        // do nothing
    }


    if (reloadProgressBlock) {
        this.reloadProgressBlock(this.currentStep);
    }
    this.currentStep = section;
    var sectionElement = $('opc-' + section);
    sectionElement.addClassName('allow');
    this.accordion.openSection('opc-' + section);
    if(!reloadProgressBlock) {
        this.resetPreviousSteps();
    }
},
```